# SFTP - how to tunnel to private AWS server behind AWS NAT

Tags: tunnel, sftp

I need to SFTP connect to a AWS server behind a NAT server in a private subnet.  Login to both the NAT server and the private subnet server is done using private SSH keys.

In windows, there is WinSCP which lets you create a SSH tunnel through the NAT server and then connect to the private subnet server.

What options exist in the OS X environment?
Fugu is old.
No other GUI seems to support SSH Tunnels

I have yet to figure out the terminal command lines or combination of terminal command lines and existing SFTP GUIs that let me tunnel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use local TCP forwarding in `ssh`, for example:

```
ssh -L 2222:private:22 user@gateway
```

And then connect any of your graphical tools to the private server by connecting to `localhost:2222`, or just use again command line `sftp`:

```
sftp private_user@localhost -P 2222
```

Comment: Thank you @Jakuje.  For whatever reason previous answers just did not make total sense to me but your answer helped me do this.